# How to perform element-wise product in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch

I have two torch tensors a and b. Tensor a has the shape of [batch_size, emb_size] and Tensor b has the shape of [num_of_words, emb_size]. I want to do the element-wise product on these two tensors instead of dot product.

I noticed that "*" can perform element-wise product but it doesn't fit my case.

For example, batch_size = 3, emb_size = 2, num_of_words = 5.

```py
a = torch.rand((3,2))
b = torch.rand((5,2))
```

I want to get something like:

```py
torch.cat([a[0]*b, a[1]*b, a[2]*b]).view(3, 5, 2)
```

but I want to do this in an efficient and elegant way.

Comment: can torch accept numpy arrays as input?

Comment: It can easily create a Tensor from a numpy.ndarray. But in my case, my tensors are all stored in GPU. It's quite time-consuming to use numpy operations and then transfer the result tensor back to GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
a.unsqueeze(1) * b
```

PyTorch supports [broadcasting semantics](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) but you need to make sure the singleton dimensions are in the correct locations.